# Why use Varnish pipe?

Tags: caching, proxy, pipe, varnish

The documentation isn't very specific on this subject and it really only explains what happens when you call the pipe subroutine.  Why would you return (pipe) in a Varnish VCL and what are some things you would do in the subroutine vcl_pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why would you return (pipe) in a Varnish VCL...?

I typically use return(pipe) to avoid Varnish timeots & post-processing of request (by example when serving huge files) [1]

Pipe also is something you should use if you want to use websockets [2]

> what are some things you would do in the subroutine vcl_pipe?

I've only seen websockets instructions and the typical (default VCl includes it) connection close setting

```
set bereq.http.connection = "close"
```

[1] https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExamplePipe

[2] https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/websockets.html